# What is the security risk of having longer Refresh token in Authorization server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth-refresh-token

We have a client application is interacting with application with oauth authentication. We dont want to authenticate the user every time when the refresh token expires .So , we thought that we can keep refresh token expiration time until 1 year. What is the security risk if we have this type of set up with longer refresh tokens

Comment: This is an antipattern according to an offset of Google docs: https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/antipatterns/oauth-long-expiration why not just refresh? It should be simple enough, if you get an error that the token is expired, make the call to refresh it

Comment: If refresh token expires, authorization server will not grant new access token. Client has login again to get new access token.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the security risk if we have this type of set up with longer
> refresh tokens

Refresh tokens are bearer tokens so whosoever holding it could use it to obtain a new `access token` from the `authorization server` until it expires. Therefore, a `refresh token` that has a very long lifespan could theoretically give infinite power to the token bearer to get a new access token. The newly obtained access token then could be used to access the protected resources anytime. The bearer of the refresh token could be a legitimate user or a malicious user. Like access tokens, it is advisable to use a short lifespan for refresh tokens. The validation time for refresh token could be increased upto a certain extent in highly trusted systems & communications.